# Are there any risks to having different Kafka topics that process different file formats?

Tags: apache-kafka

For the same cluster of machines that run kafka, I have different topics that process messages of different types, say one topic for Protobuf, one for Avro, and one for String messages.

Could there be any problems with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

This is a totally valid use case as long as you employ multiple producers/consumers with different serializers/deserializers for each topic.